Salesforce SOQL Query through Azure Data Factory
With the new OAUTH2 LinkedService connection established we ran into the following issue in our pipelines.
When performing the following query through Azure Data Factory:
SELECT Id FROM Account
WHERE SystemModstamp > @{variables('Lastmodified Account')}
OR LastModifiedDate >  @{variables('Lastmodified Account')}

We receive the following error.
The response from Salesforce Bulk API indicates a failure. Please check the error message to understand the reason or contact Salesforce support. Error message: {"id":"750aV00000BJOgGQAX","operation":"queryAll","object":"Account","createdById":"00509000009qvimAAA","createdDate":"2024-11-11T13:36:55.000+0000","systemModstamp":"2024-11-11T13:36:56.000+0000","state":4,"concurrencyMode":"Parallel","contentType":"CSV","apiVersion":"54.0","lineEnding":"LF","columnDelimiter":"COMMA","jobType":"V2Query","numberRecordsProcessed":0,"retries":0,"totalProcessingTime":0,"numberRecordsFailed":0,"errorMessage":"Unexpected exception encountered in query processing. Please contact support with the following id: (removed)
We tried writing the correct datetime format instead of variables which returns the same unhandled exception, at the end of my latin here.
I've also seen a similar thread that got resolved using parenthesis outside of the where clausule, this in my case did not resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Where it says "(removed)" was it you who removed the id, or did you copy that also?

I removed the support id myself for the purpose of this topic.

So for anyone curious, after doing some more digging, using parenthesis worked, as well as having the correct date/time format as default variable value.
Issue
Default value for variable: 2020-01-01
SELECT Id FROM Account
WHERE SystemModstamp > @{variables('Lastmodified Account')}
OR LastModifiedDate >  @{variables('Lastmodified Account')}

Solution
New default value for variable: 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z
SELECT Id FROM Account
WHERE (SystemModstamp > @{variables('Lastmodified Account')}
OR LastModifiedDate >  @{variables('Lastmodified Account')})

